# invisible characters UTF-8 visual studio 2022

Tags: character-encoding, visual-studio-2022

i don't see invisble characters in visual studio 2022 and i don't know why.

to realize it, I had to copy the line to notepad ++ and change the encoding to ANSI.
The line is :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Notes, new {â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹ @class = "form-control", @style = "min-height:6em; resize:vertical;" }â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹)
```

If you change you're encodage to UTF-8, u will see invisble characters.how is this possible, normally we go to utf-8 to see the invisible characters?

The line in UTF8

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Notes, new {​​​​​​​​ @class = "form-control", @style = "min-height:6em; resize:vertical;" }​​​​​​​​)
```

how can i see his characters in visual studio?

Thank you !

Comment: Note: avoid using "ANSI". There is no such charset. ANSI is an organization, and what people thinks about encoding ANSI, usually it is some hybrid between some ECMA/ANSI/ISO and Microsoft own take on standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Visual Studio extension to see the invisible characters in your code.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaneRay.InvisibleCharacterVisualizer

[image: Example]

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support VS2022 as of this date.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that for *ANSI*, you mean *cp1252*.

The text `â€‹` in cp1252 is equivalent of the character U+200B in UTF-8, which it is the character for "ZERO WIDTH SPACE".

Such characters should be avoided in source code (but eventually on inline documentation). Usually the origin is a copy/paste from a website, where some hidden spaces are inserted in place of tags (e.g. to change font or colour). I consider this as a bug of such web-site, but also of the code copied.
Note: maybe there is an other origin of such text (but a repeated sequence usually hints at such copy/paste errors).

Note: to me, it doesn't seem malicious use of Unicode characters (see recent CVEs for such malicious use on codes), but because these recent CVEs, I really recommend to remove such characters.

For more information, you can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space (for this character), and a list of other white spaces (and zero width spaces) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character.

Comment: Indeed, these are not really errors since the project compiles, but I would like to see them for them removed.it makes mistakes in intellisence